# Heuristics of Cohen-Lenstra-Martinet

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $h(d)$ be the class numbers of the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. There are some heuristics of Cohen-Lenstra-Martinet about divisibility of class numbers. Do
they say anything about the density of primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ for which
$h(2p)$ is a multiple of $4.$?

Answer (score 14):

The answer to the question as stated is "no". The original Cohen—Lenstra—Martinet heuristics say nothing about the $2$-Sylow subgroup of the class group of a quadratic field.

These heuristics were later modified by Gerth to take into account genus theory, see F. Gerth III, [Densities for ranks of certain parts of $p$-class groups](https://eudml.org/doc/89810), Proc. AMS 99, and Gerth's modification does make predictions about the average behaviour of the $2$-Sylow of a "random" real quadratic number field. However, the fields you are considering form a density $0$ subfamily of the family of all real quadratic fields, so again, Gerth's heuristic says nothing about those.

However, **a complete answer to the question "when is $h(2p)$ divisible by $4$" is known**. This happens if and only if $p$ splits completely in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8,\sqrt{1+i})$. One says that "$K$ is a *governing field* for the $4$-rank of class groups in this family". Since $K$ is a field of degree $8$, Chebotarev implies that the density of $p$ for which $h(2p)$ is divisible by $4$ is $1/8$.

For a summary of what is known about $4$- and $8$-ranks of these class groups and their governing fields, together with many references, see P. Koymans and D. Milovic, [Spins of prime ideals and the negative Pell equation
$x^2 − 2py^2 = −1$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10337.pdf), [Compos. Math. 155.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/abs/spins-of-prime-ideals-and-the-negative-pell-equation-x22py21/CC1A0361F305897BD0A62093FBDDAFA1)